# Add Button in Tab Bar - Small Modal with Blurred Background

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, uitabbar

I'm trying to have an add button in my tab bar controller that when clicked will bring up a table view modal. I want the modal to be smaller than the full screen and the background view to be blurred. Can anyone help me with this?

Relevant code is below:

AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        return tue
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController is AddViewController {
            if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddModal"){
                tabBarController.present(newVC, animated: true)
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Modal View Controller:

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {

    var list = [
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4"
    ]

    var text: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view = UITableView(frame: .zero)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }

}

extension AddViewController {
    private var tableView: UITableView {
        return self.view as! UITableView
    }
}

extension AddViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tabBarController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            return
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to create a custom transition and implement transitioningDelegate for UIViewController. Add it to your tab and when you call `present`, it will use your transition. Within your transition, you need to set the frame you want to present to.. IE: `toViewController.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds.inset(15, 15)`

Comment: @Brandon just to clarify, the transitioningDelegate would be for the AddViewController in this case? and same thing for the toViewController you gave as an example?

Comment: Do I pt the toViewController.view.frame part in the toViewController or the AppDelegate?

Comment: to show the view controller as a modal, rather than just present viewcontroller, use:   

 `newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
 newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
tabBarController.present(newVC, animated: true)`